# transfer files from mobile to raspberry pi via Bluetooth

Tags: raspbian

i want to transfer a file from my mobile to raspberry pi via Bluetooth as i am using a Bluetooth module with raspberry pi can you please explain how is this possible

Comment: What is the main use case - transferring file or using bluetooth?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you use an iPhone or Android device? Please give us more information!

Comment: @Kangkan transfering files

Comment: @Bendim andriod device ..also is there any command or code for creating a directory in mobile phone when connected with bluetooth which will show the content of pendrive that is connected to the usb port of raspberry pi

Comment: If it is only about transferring file one time, I would suggest using wi-fi and Samba. If it is repeatitive like sync of files and contacts OwnCloud should be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer file from you mobile to Pi using OBEX Server. I used in Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I don't try on other version but it may be work on there also.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=963751#p963751 
just follow steps which mentioned on this link.